# Can't use class filed in the class implimenttion

Tags: c++, class

This gives me C3867: (You tried to take the address of a member function without qualifying the member function with its class name and the address-of operator.)

```
    //.h
class Entity
{
private:
    const std::ranlux24_base random_engine(std::random_device);
    void Print();
};

    //.cpp
            void  Entity::Print()
            {
          std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(0, 10);
          cout << uniform_dist(random_engine);
            }
```

New in C++. If i declare random_engine localy:

```
void  Entity::Print()
{
std::random_device rd;
std::ranlux24_base e1(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(1, 3);
int val = uniform_dist(e1);
}
```

- all warks...Can't undestand what is reason..

Comment: You declared `random_engine` as a member function (returning `const std::ranlux24_base` and taking one parameter of type `std::random_device`). Did you intend for it to be a data member instead?

Comment: Yes... data member... like field in C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want a random device and prng engine as either static class members or local variables in your .cpp file. In C++11 the distribution objects use a provided random engine, properly seeded with a device-provided initial seed, to generate their distribution. It is important you only construct the device *once*, and provide the seeding *once*, if possible. When you look at the code you present that "works" that is exactly what it does.

So if you want to avoid recreating a device and engine with each invoke to `Entity::Print()`, you have several options. One is to make them class-static members:

In your header:

```
class Entity
{
private:
    static std::random_device rd;
    static std::ranlux24_base rng;
    void Print();
};
```

In your .cpp file:

```
std::random_device Entity::rd;
std::ranlux24_base Entity::rng(Entity::rd());

void  Entity::Print()
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(0, 10);
    std::cout << uniform_dist(rng);
}
```

But making them class static is fairly pointless if they're just used exclusively in the Entity.cpp file's `Entity::Print()` method, in which case you could just do this:

In header:

```
class Entity
{
private:
    void Print();
};
```

In cpp file:

```
void  Entity::Print()
{
    static std::random_device rd;
    static std::ranlux24_base rng(rd());

    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(0, 10);
    std::cout << uniform_dist(rng);
}
```

Comment: isn't local static  recreated every time? i am cary very match about perfomance and memory...

Comment: @Brans No. Its a one-shot hit. Both of the cases above will create a single device and engine object (unless `Entity` is a template class, in which case you get one per type-expansion). That is the reason I made them `static`. I somewhat figured you'd have a lot of `Entity` objects doing their `Print()` operation.

Comment: yes i have many Entity objects.. I am not using SEED value. When we are using random_device insted of seed we will got unpredictable sequences(i need this) of values AFAK

Comment: @Brans I figured as much. The above code should do what you're looking for, most likely the second example will be sufficient. Just don't use the device. Use a defined seed instead if you want a reproducible sequence.

Comment: I can use time() for a seed, but what is bad with device? It is special for that so i made a colclusion that it may be bertter..

Comment: @Brans Wait. do you want predictable or non-predictable sequences? Predictable means you use the *same* static seed when initializing the engine. For reasons I hope are as obvious as the name, `time()` is not  the same for very long. `(1)` is a static seed. So is `(2)`, and `(42)`, etc. `time()` is *not*.

Comment: It are  genetic algoritms, modeling of evolution and so on. So i need everytime non-predictable and not repitable sequences... i don't need to repeat sequence from seed...

Comment: @Brans Ah... ok. then just use what is in the answer. No seeding required on your part (thats what the random device is doing for you).

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this. You are re-defining the class in .cpp file. You shouldn't.

```
    //.h
class Entity
{
private:
    const std::ranlux24_base random_engine(std::random_device);
    void Print();
};

    //.cpp
void  Entity::Print()
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(0, 10);
    cout << uniform_dist(random_engine);
}
```